# Using MySql mysqldump under windows

Tags: mysql

I'm working on MySql 5.6 under Windows7 and trying to take a data snapshot using 'mysqldump' command, that in order to set database replication.

I'm using the following command,

```
mysqldump --user myuser --password --all-databases --master-data > dbdump.db
```

but I get the error,

```
mysqldump: Error: Binlogging on server not active
```

I have set on the file 'my-default.ini',

> log-bin=mysql-bin
>
> server-id=1

and restarted MySql service after that.

Any suggestnts?
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: are you sure this is the config file being used by mysql? i think it's usually `my.ini`

Comment: that is the only ini file i found at the installation folder "Program Files\MySql\MySql Server 5.6" @Yazan